# Changing rEFIt default boot

Tags: refit

New Linux (Ubuntu 13.04) user with a 4,1 Macbook and I'm unable to set Ubuntu as my default boot with rEFIt. I used the guide below, but I do not get the same Terminal output. I get this instead:
~
~
~
~
~
~
"/etc/efi/refit/refit.conf" [New DIRECTORY]

http://thehungrycoder.com/tutorial/setting-linux-as-default-in-refit-boot-loader.html

Answer (score 2):

First, rEFIt hasn't been updated in over three years. You may want to consider switching to [rEFInd,](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) which is under active development. (I maintain it.) Among other improvements, rEFInd has much better support for Linux and better options for setting the default OS.

Second, there's an error in the specification of the file to be edited; it should be `/efi/refit/refit.conf`, not `/etc/efi/refit/refit.conf`. (If you switch to rEFInd, it should be `/efi/refind/refind.conf`.)

Comment: Is this file in the Linux partition, or the OSX partition?

Comment: Normally it's on OS X's root (`/`) partition; but if rEFIt/rEFInd is installed on the EFI System Partition (ESP) or some other location, it would be relative to that partition's root.